# İm trying to do a list while using json but i have a problem : "Binding element 'product' implicitly has an 'any' type react native"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

this is my flat list

```
        <ChosenHeader />
        <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          <FlatList
            style={{ margin: 10, width: "100%" }}
            numColumns={2}
            data={products}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Card product={item} />}

          />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
```

but when i create a card, its geting an error:

```
 Card = ({ product }) => (
    <View>
     
    </View>
  );
```

product is getting an error. how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
Card = ({product} : { product: any}) => (
    <View>
     
    </View>
  );
```